# sql optimization: count all rows through subquery or own query / other improvements

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I'm trying to improve my mysql query. At first I'm trying to optimize that simple one:

```
SELECT * , 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(id)
            FROM animal 
            WHERE type = :type  AND timestampadopt > 0 AND (date BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d'))          
            ) AS countanimals
        FROM animal
        WHERE type = :type  AND timestampadopt > 0 AND (date BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
        ORDER BY timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1, 20;
```

COLUMNS:

```
id | timestampadd | timestampadopt | dateborn | animaltype | gender | chipped | smalldescger | smalldesceng | imagepath
```

On that affected site I loop all animals, with pagination. So you can see 20 animals and for the next 20 you have to use the next button.

I need to know for the pagination how many sites have to be displayed, so I have to count how many animals in total are, that is what the subquery does.

I measured with profiling the times and get following results:

**0.0047s** for the total query,
**0.0023s** for the subquery

In the database are only **5 rows**!

On that site I offer some filters, like age +/- 1 year and is the animal already adopted, because of that I need the WHERE clause on both, which probably takes up the most performance, followed by the order by clause which is necessary to display the new ones first.

P.S. I need all columns from the table, I did some testings and `SELECT *` had same runtimes then selecting all 10 columns manually like some people recommend.

EDIT:
Would it be worth to exclude the smalltext (varchar 250), imagpath (varchar 50) columns in a own table and inner join them, the other columns I could probably need for later filter. But type, gender, chipped are tinyints.

Any improvement tips for me?

Should I do the subquery in a own query outside of the main one?

**Edit: 31.07**

```
SELECT a.* , c.cnt AS countanimals
        FROM animal  a
        JOIN (
            Select a1.date AS date1, a1.tmstmpadopt AS tmstmpadopt1, a1.type AS type1, COUNT(a1.id) as cnt 
            FROM animal a1
            GROUP BY date1, tmstmpadopt1, type1
            ) c on (a.date = c.date1 AND a.tmstmpadopt = c.tmstmpadopt1 AND a.type = c.type1)

        WHERE a.type = 1 AND tmstmpadopt = 0 AND (date BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 100 YEAR AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d')- INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
        ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
        LIMIT 1, 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline view may help you. So try this

```
SELECT a.*,c.cnt AS countanimals
FROM animal a 
       join (Select a1.dateborn, a1.timestampadopt, count(a1.id) as cnt 
             from animals a1
             Where a1.timestampadopt > 0
               and a1.type = :type
             group by a1.dateborn, a1.timestampadopt) c on (a.dateborn = c.dateborn and a.timestampadopt = c.timestampadopt)
WHERE a.type = :type
AND a.timestampadopt > 0 
AND a.dateborn BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d')-INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1, 20;
```

Comment: Great, it looks like its reasonably faster already ~20%, maybe with a lot more rows the difference is even bigger. Is that because of the join or the group by on the date row ? Could i group by type and timesampadopt too for even better results ?

Comment: I have added timestampadopt in that inline view. Now it shouldn't give any difference. If its still showing difference the post some sample data

Comment: I meaned to remove in the join "where a1.timestampadopt > 0" and use group by like you did on the a1.dateborn. Is group by in that case faster then Where or does the join make the difference ? Because we already call a "where a1.timestampadopt > 0" in the main query.

Comment: no we should add that condition then only volume of data will be reduced because you want all the record for which timestampadopt > 0 only. I have added that timestampadopt in select and group by clause and add the same in on clause a.timestampadopt.= c.timestampadopt. It will automatically filter that

Comment: Oh i think i understood know, instead of doing the same work again and check all rows if the date matches like the main query does we can group them and remove that step ? So in the join query less work have to be done then earlier with the subquery ?

Comment: yes that is correct. General thumb rule for aggregation filter out unwanted records and then group the data

Comment: I added 100k rows and tried now your example and the old one, Unfortunately your solution is less efficient. With your solution i recieve about 0,13 seconds and the old one 1 second. According to explain both variants check 100k of rows.

Comment: I don't think so...In old one subquery will be executed for each row executed by parent query. So 100k records will be filtered each time and then do aggregation. But In my solution that inline view will be executed first time only. In this case it should take less than the previous one. So check other things like network etc

Comment: Check my upload there is a comparison in time and explain with your method and the old one: https://imgur.com/a/GCsao9h  GROUP BY seems to work like a filesort and have to check same like where every single row.

Comment: which version of mysql you are using

Comment: Ähm..
Server-Typ: MySQL
Server-Version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04 Client Version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev? Under extensions i have many INNODB_xxx

Comment: create composite index dateborn, timestampadopt and then check my solution. If possible post the execution plan

Comment: I did some tests with different composite indexes: https://imgur.com/a/GCsao9h last 2 images is with timestampadopt and dateborn, but still all variant seem to be more efficient

Comment: no need of different composite index.. we need composite index dateborn, timestampadopt for these column and in the same order only. post the explain plan for this

Comment: I dont know how to create that plan =), but in the latest 2 examples i did a composite index with the 2 columns we said. Check latest image https://imgur.com/a/GCsao9h tmstmpadopt is timestampadopt and dateborn is date

Comment: I think you are created index in this order  timestampadopt, dateborn. If I'm correct then please change the order  to dateborn, timestampadopt.

Comment: if i change them like you have said on explain reaching values like 68k and 68k for both variants, opposite it is 34k, 68k on your method and 34k,34k on the old one. (rows) I have edited the main question to show you my modified query on your answer, probably i did some mistake on take over.

Comment: I added timestamp as index too, because using often order by in other querys and also on this. Like that im reaching on both querys 68k and both are similar fast like that. But im not able to speed up the query with your method.

Comment: with the index on timestamp i can reduce the rows for primary from 68k to almost zero rows, thats nice.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the count on the script, as you process the rows, you can count them.

Comment: Because of the Site Limitation (Limit $start, $end) i cant count all rows. As result i only get 20 rows. But i need all rows to calculate the pagination. I edit the question so its more clear now ;D.